# how to make formula into vba statement

Tags: excel, vba

i have the following formula:

```
=indirect($a$1&"!"&"A2:b6")
```

but when i code this as a formula, the line fails, how do i fix this?

```
.Range("A2:B6").Formula = "=INDIRECT(Sheet1!$B$1&!&"A2:b6")"
```

Comment: Doubles quotes which are inside of a string literal need to be escaped. Use `""` rather than simply `"`, so `"=indirect($a$1&""!""&""A2:b6"")"`

Comment: getting an application error on same line now.
    Range("A2:B6").Formula = "=INDIRECT(Sheet1!$B$1&!&""A2:I10000"")"

Answer (score 1):

so here is the fix, needed some more quotes

```
.Range("A2:B6").Formula = "=INDIRECT(Sheet1!$B$1&""!""&""A2:I10000"")"
```